# Codemirror autoCloseBarckets misbehaves with CSS and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, codemirror, codemirror-modes

I have autoCloseBrackets v5.5.0 for Codemirror which misbehaves with CSS and Javascript. The following picture describes how it misbehaves with javascript. Please help.[image: This is how it misbehaves]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer. I was using an older version of codemirror.js so i updated it. No it works just fine.